# Mutable Array ObjectAtIndexs

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I'm using the following code to create a label from an `NSMutableArray` :

```
CGRect punti = CGRectMake(270, 200, 50, 50);
CGRect punti2 = CGRectMake(370, 200, 50, 50);
CGRect punti3 = CGRectMake(470, 200, 50, 50);

[_Cordinate3lettere insertObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:[NSValue valueWithCGRect:punti],[NSValue valueWithCGRect:punti],[NSValue valueWithCGRect:punti], nil] atIndex:0];

UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
NSIndexSet *indexSet = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 2)];

// Error occurs on line below
label.frame = [[_Cordinate3lettere objectAtIndexs:indexSet] CGRectValue];
label.text = @"a"; 
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:0];
//label.font =
[self.view addSubview:label];
```

However, the following line generates an error.

```
label.frame = [[_Cordinate3lettere objectAtIndexs:indexSet] CGRectValue];
```

The error received is `No visible @interface for NSMutableArray declares the selector "objectAtIndexs"`

What is causing this error and how I can resolve it?

Comment: What is this supposed to do? Set 2 frames on one UILabel? That won't work. What's the purpose of that NSIndexSet?

Comment: Perhaps using `objectAtIndex:(nsinteger)index` suits your need better, because i cannot imagine a reason to use an indexset to set a frame.

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo in your call. The method name is:

```
- (NSArray *)objectsAtIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)indexes
```

Not `objectAtIndexs`

Comment: Which will then lead to the "NSArray does not recognize selector CGRectValue" error.

Comment: you'll get back an array with objects. now you have to take out the right object and call CGRectValue at this object

Comment: it really wouldn't make any sense to call something `objectsAtIndexes` and expect a single object back.

Comment: I have a set of coordinates and when there is the call of the index 0 the values that came back are, for example, (200, 200,50 ,50) (300, 300, 50, 50) (400, 400, 50, 50) and those coordinates create a label

Answer (score 0):

Replace `label.frame = [[_Cordinate3lettere objectAtIndexs:indexSet] CGRectValue];`

with:

```
NSArray *frames = [_Cordinate3lettere objectAtIndexes:indexSet];
label.frame = [[frame objectAtIndex:0 /*or whatever index you want here*/] CGRectValue];
```